# Determine if is a vector space or not

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In the lines below, determine whether each of the sets given is a vector space or not. 
Even understanding what is vector space, i can't answer this question. I don't need just the answer, i need to understand why.

$A) S = \{\begin{pmatrix}
         x  \\
        y  \\
        z  \\
        \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3  :  x+y+z = 1\}$

$B)S = \{\begin{pmatrix}
         a & 1  \\
        b & c \\
        \end{pmatrix} : a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$C)S = \{a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 : a_0,a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R}^+\}$

$D)S = \{\begin{pmatrix}
         x & x + y  \\
        x + y & y \\
        \end{pmatrix} : x , y \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$E)S = \{\begin{pmatrix}
         a & 0  \\
        0 & b \\
        \end{pmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: This question is a simple application of the definition of what it means to be a vector space. Consult a definition.

Comment: I voted to close the question as too broad (five questions in all).  It was a toss up for reasons; it could very well be closed as "off-topic: missing context".

Comment: As @AOrtiz notes, **Definitions** are your friend. You claim you know what a vector space is; then ask yourself for each of the five questions, does it satisfy the definition/criteria of a vector space, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
A) Can zero vector be in such a set?

B) If we add two such matrices, we have 2 in the place, where 1 was.

C) These are polynomials of degree $\leq 2$.

D), E) Easy to verify that yes.

Comment: A,D and E i get it now. B i believe is because you can't find the "0" matrix. C i still didn't understand why, for me is a vector space even multiplying by a negative constant, because only the coefficients must be real positive numbers.

Comment: @Carlos You are right. I thought about transformation $x\mapsto a+bx+cx^2$, but it is a subspace of polynomials, not a transformation. Corrected.